# IE (10) blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors - show content

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer-10

Currently having an issue with a client that is getting the following error when loading a certain website:

[image]

I have added the site to trusted sites and enabled 'display mixed content' through GPO.  Popup messages still appears and still have to hit show content for it to continue to the site.

System clock settings are correct and I really do not think its wise to uncheck 'warn of sites with mismatch certs' to bypass this warning.

Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: What site it try to open ? If it's for an internal server now cert are really cheap to buy.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not internal.

Comment: Is it a public website?  Can you share the URL?

Comment: www.chartinsurance.com.  loaded in google and it displayed a nice message actually explaining the warning[unlike IE] - the sec cert is from aig.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Press Alt+X or Tools in internet explorer
2. Press Security tab and Change the Security level for the zone(internet) as low
3. Also do same for 'Trusted site' zone as low
4. Press 'Sites' button to add the 'www.chartinsurance.com' to the zone
5. Press Apply and OK
6. Restart the browser.

If the issue still persist then follow the below steps

1. Press Alt+X or Tools in internet explorer
2. Press Advanced tab and unchecked the 'Warn about certificate address mismatch' option
3. Press Apply and OK
4. Restart the computer.

Comment: Chart was already in trusted through GPO and no way I can remove warn about cert mismatches in a business environment, although it did work!  Had client contact the site, issue is legit on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Was nothing gpo/client side that would 'make the message' go away without compromising security.  Issue was with the site itself and actually having a mismatched cert.